# Strange behavior in react/redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my React/Redux app, I make a backend API call to create an entry in a calendar. This is initiated in my handler function which calls the action creator.

Once this initial step is done, I check to see if the entry the user has just created has the same date as the current date my calendar component showing. If so, I call the backend API to get calendar events. I do this to refresh the calendar.

As I step through the process, everything seems to be working fine BUT my calendar does not show updated data.

Here comes the weird part: as I step through this process, everything works and the calendar updates fine. In other words, if I somehow slow down the process, everything seems to be working perfectly fine.

If I don't slow down the process, the calendar fails to update. There are no errors. And as I said, as I step through the process, I see that the API returns correct data, action creator to `SET_CALENDAR_EVENTS` gets called which then calls the reducer and the reducer sets the data.

Like I said, there are no problems except if I let it happen without slowing down the process, the calendar doesn't update.

Any idea what's causing this? Any suggestions?

My handler function code looks like this:

```js
clickHandleCreateEvent(event) {

   // Call API
   this.props.actions.createEvent(event);

   // Get active date
   const activeDate = this.props.activeDate;

   if(activeDate === event.eventDate) {

      this.props.actions.getCalendarEvents(activeDate);
   }

}
```

UPDATE: 
Here's my getCalendarEvents function:

```
export const getCalendarEntries = (calendarId, date) => {

    // Create get calendar entries object
    var request = {
        id: calendarId,
        date: date
    };

    // Get calendar entries
    return (dispatch) => fetch('/api/calendars/entries', fetchOptionsPost(request))
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.ok) {
                // Got events
                parseJSON(response)
                    .then(entries => {
                        dispatch(setEvents(entries))
                    })
                    .then(() => dispatch(setCalendarIsLoading(false)))
            } else {
                // Couldn't get data
                dispatch(setBadRequest(true))
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: I don't know how is the rest of your code is but is it possible somewhere you are setting some state value and reading it. setState works asynchronously so slowing down might give enough time to set.

Comment: I actually never use `setState()`. I've had unpredictable behavior with `setState()` so I always go through the store. There are absolutely no `setState()`'s in my whole app.

Comment: I bet both `createEvent` and `getCalendarEvents` are async and you are getting a "dirty read" due to network latency. Does  `createEvent` return a promise?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Yes, they're both async events and createEvent does return a promise.

Comment: @Sam Then try to do this `createEvent(event).then(() => {
  // rest of your code.
})`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Just updated the original post with my 'getCalendarEvents()' function.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I'm already doing what you're suggesting.

Comment: @Sam Well, not really. I'm suggesting to wait for server response before firing another request to load data. In your code there is no guarantee which request hits server first.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I'm not clear. `createEvent()` and `getCalendarEvents()` are not even chained. Are you suggesting for me to chain them?

Comment: Yes. I'm suggesting you to call `getCalendarEvents ` after server has reported ok on `createEvent` call inside `clickHandleCreateEvent`. Otherwise there is no guarantee which request hits backend first. And you might read old data from the db while request to add event were still traveling somewhere over the wire.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko You're absolutely right! That did the trick! Thank you. If you post your comment as an answer, I can accept it. I'd like you to get credit for your help. I'll up vote your comment as well. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both `createEvent` and `getCalendarEvents` are async functions involving network communication there is no guarantee which request reaches the server first. So you might read old data while `createEvent` request were still travelling over the wire.

To avoid this you need to synchronize both requests ie call `getCalendarEvents` after the server has responded ok to `createEvent` request.

```
clickHandleCreateEvent(event) {

   // Call API
   return this.props.actions
     .createEvent(event);
     .then(() => {
       // Get active date
       const activeDate = this.props.activeDate;

       if(activeDate === event.eventDate) {
         return this.props.actions.getCalendarEvents(activeDate)
       }
     })
}
```

Comment: You're a strong developer my friend! Best of luck to you. I don't think you need much luck to find great opportunities. Thanks again.

Comment: @Sam Glad I could help. The best of luck to you, too.